# How to display record one by one using Django template (html) and model

Tags: django, templates, view

In my code below all the questions & related images stored in my table are coming on same page at one go but I want only first question and its image to appear and than when user clicks on next button the second question along with its image should come, this should repeat till end of records in the table.

**View**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from quiz.models import Quiz, Question
    
def playQuiz(request):
    data=Question.objects.filter(__isnull=False)
    res=render(request,'quiz/quiz_play.html',{'data':data})
    return res
```

**Template**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     {% for data in data %}
      <div><h1> {{data.qs}} </h1></div>
      <div> <img src="{{ data.qip.url }}" height=300> </div>
      <input type="button" name="next-btn" value="NEXT">
     {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use the the same value `data` as the queryset you're iterating over (`data`). Maybe use: `for question in data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Paginator to achieve this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/). It will automatically handle the going forward or backward.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

from quiz.models import Quiz, Question

def playQuiz(request):
    data=Question.objects.filter(__isnull=False)
    paginator = Paginator(data, 1) # Show 1 data per page.

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    res = render(request, 'quiz/quiz_play.html', {'page_obj': page_obj})
    return res
```

In your template you will use it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 {% for data in page_obj %}
  <div><h1> {{data.qs}} </h1></div>
  <div> <img src="{{ data.qip.url }}" height=300> </div>
  <input type="button" name="next-btn" value="NEXT">
 {% endfor %}
 <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay for all your help. Implemented the same now working fine.